# PyTorch - how to print the total number of trainable parameters for a single layer?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to print the total number of trainable parameters for a single PyTorch layer.  For example, given:

```
import torch.nn as nn

conv_layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,
                       out_channels=16,
                       kernel_size=3)
```

Based on others answers here is what I've tried so far:

```
print(conv_layer)
```

prints:

```
Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
```

and:

```
print(conv_layer.parameters())
```

prints:

```
<generator object Module.parameters at 0x7fe99b7e1740>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived from [this](https://saturncloud.io/blog/check-the-total-number-of-parameters-in-a-pytorch-model/) article:

```
import torch.nn as nn

conv_layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,
                       out_channels=16,
                       kernel_size=3)

num_trainable_params = sum([p.numel() for p in conv_layer.parameters()])

print('\n' + 'num_trainable_params = ' + str(num_trainable_params) + '\n')
```

Since it's a generator, you can iterate over it. In your case, the `param_count_by_layer` will be a list of length 1.

Also, [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-do-i-check-the-number-of-parameters-of-a-model/4325/26) posts cautions users if they use this approach while using a Tensorflow model;

> If you use `torch_model.parameters()`, the layers batchnorm in torch
> only show 2 values: weight and bias, while in tensorflow, 4 values of
> batchnorm are shown, which are gamma, beta and moving mean and moving var.

> The 2 later values are non-trainable
> parameters and they don’t show up in the `torch_model.parameters()`. If
> you compare `torch_model.parameters()` and `tf_model.trainable_variables`,
> they should be equal.

Comment: I made a minor update to your code to include the sum

Comment: But that would give you the total number of trainable parameters. This doesn't matter if you have only one layer but I think it should be summed for every layer. So; `[sum(p.numel()) for p in conv_layer.parameters()]`, or am I missing something?

Comment: My question was how to get the total number of trainable parameters for a single layer, so this is what I was looking for.  I'll edit my question to make it more clear.